# Efficient lookup of details of aggregate rows without combining columns (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by

An open source project I'm helping out with is looking up details of aggregates by storing a column which is a combination of the value and the row ID. This is causing me almost physical pain.

However, I can't seem to change it to a different implementation without hurting performance.
I'm testing this on the latest MySQL 8.0.

**Generate demo data**

Takes about 3 minutes to run on my desktop

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `demo_data`;
CREATE TABLE `demo_data` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_a` INT NOT NULL,
  `cat_b` INT NOT NULL,
  `cat_c` INT NOT NULL,
  `value` INT NOT NULL,
  `details` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', # representing several columns, including connections to other tables for joins
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS generate_data;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_data()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  SET autocommit = 0; 

  WHILE i < 2200000 DO
    INSERT INTO `demo_data` (`cat_a`,`cat_b`,`cat_c`,`value`,`details`) VALUES (
      ROUND(RAND()*50000),  
      1,      
      2,      
      ROUND(RAND()*120000),
      'important details'
    );
    SET i = i + 1;

    IF i%1000=0 THEN 
        COMMIT;     
    END IF;
  END WHILE;

  SET i = 0;
  WHILE i < 300000 DO
    INSERT INTO `demo_data` (`cat_a`,`cat_b`,`cat_c`,`value`,`details`) VALUES (
      ROUND(RAND()*50000),  
      ROUND(RAND()*3),      
      ROUND(RAND()*3),      
      ROUND(RAND()*120000),
      'important details'
    );
    SET i = i + 1;

    IF i%1000=0 THEN 
        COMMIT;     
    END IF;
  END WHILE;

  SET autocommit =1;
  COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL generate_data();
```

**Create a "concise" data table with the aggregate combined with the raw data**

Takes about 8 seconds on my desktop

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS demo_data_concise;

CREATE TABLE demo_data_concise AS 
          SELECT
            result.id,
            value,
            valueAndId,
            cat_a,
            cat_b,
            cat_c
          FROM (
              SELECT MIN(value * 1000000000 + result.id) valueAndId
              FROM demo_data result
              WHERE value > 0
              GROUP BY cat_a, cat_b, cat_c
            ) MinValuesWithId
            JOIN demo_data result ON result.id = valueAndId % 1000000000;
```

**Usage of the concise table**

Takes under 200ms on my desktop

```
        SELECT
          result.*
        FROM (
          SELECT MIN(valueAndId) valueAndId
          FROM demo_data_concise
          WHERE 1
            AND value > 0 # some of the real values are negative, leaving it here just for the reference
            AND cat_b = 1 # cat_b clause is optional
            AND cat_c = 2 # cat_c clause is optional
          GROUP BY cat_a
          ORDER BY valueAndId
          LIMIT 100 # limit can change
        ) top
        JOIN demo_data result ON result.id = valueAndId % 1000000000
        ORDER BY value, cat_a;
```

**Alternatives**

I've tried generating the concise table using a self join, ROW_NUMBER, and LATERAL -- nothing seems to even come close in terms of performance.
There must be some way to achieve these results in a better way...?!

Comment: When using a `JOIN`, be sure to qualify each column with the table name (or alias).

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`